# CORS and PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, web-services

I have a REST API server written in Python and web2py. I would like to run it at PythonAnywhere (I have a free account).

However, my REST API server runs into CORS issues. Normally, I would patch my Apache configuration to get around this, but at PythonAnywhere, I don't have this option. Am I screwed?

UPDATE:

This is the solution: Add these lines to the web2py controller...

```
if request.env.http_origin:
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.env.http_origin
```

Comment: Could you give more details about the CORS issues?  BTW this page has code for adding the appropriate headers to allow cross-site access to a web2py app -- perhaps you'll find it useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/kSUtyNcUQGI/qfiIqfUiWLwJ

Comment: If you build the rest api also other CORS headers which may be necessary like "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"